# How to subtract values from a numeric string, in Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

In Windows command-line I can print the year of the current date by doing this:

```
echo %date:~10,4%
```

result: 2016

Of course, depending on how dates are displayed in your language you need to change the `10` or `4` to get the correct sub string. But that's ok.

What I want it to print is `2015`, which is `2016 - 1`. So, how do I subtract 1 from the sub string I've just captured? There is no problem in using auxiliary variables.

Comment: this date stuff is way to complex with the windows batch shell and also kind of unreadeable. I'd suggest using PowerShell. `(Get-Date).year -1` simple and clear. gotta love powershell. put it into a variable for further use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've stated there's no problem using another variable, you can do it as follows (My environment settings use a different substring)

```
set /a "yearminus1=%date:~6,10%-1"
```

[image]

For you, I assume this will be `set /a "yearminus1=%date:~10,4%-1"`, but I can't test this.

Using the `/a` switch with `set` specifies you will be giving an expression to be evaluated, rather than just store the expression in the variable as it is.

The following operators can be used:

```
   +   Add                set /a "_num=_num+5"
   +=  Add variable       set /a "_num+=5"
   -   Subtract (or unary)set /a "_num=_num-5"
   -=  Subtract variable  set /a "_num-=5"
   *   Multiply           set /a "_num=_num*5"
   *=  Multiply variable  set /a "_num*=5"
   /   Divide             set /a "_num=_num/5"
   /=  Divide variable    set /a "_num/=5"
   %%  Modulus            set /a "_num=5%%2"
   %%= Modulus            set /a "_num%%=5" 
   !   Logical negation  0 (FALSE) ⇨ 1 (TRUE) and any non-zero value (TRUE) ⇨ 0 (FALSE)
   ~   One's complement (bitwise negation) 
   &   AND                set /a "_num=5&3"    0101 AND 0011 = 0001 (decimal 1)
   &=  AND variable       set /a "_num&=3"
   |   OR                 set /a "_num=5|3"    0101 OR 0011 = 0111 (decimal 7)
   |=  OR variable        set /a "_num|=3"
   ^   XOR                set /a "_num=5^3"    0101 XOR 0011 = 0110 (decimal 6)
   ^=  XOR variable       set /a "_num=^3"
   <<  Left Shift.    (sign bit ⇨ 0)
   >>  Right Shift.   (Fills in the sign bit such that a negative number always remains negative.)
                       Neither ShiftRight nor ShiftLeft will detect overflow.
   <<= Left Shift variable     set /a "_num<<=2"
   >>= Right Shift variable    set /a "_num>>=2"

  ( )  Parenthesis group expressions  set /a "_num=(2+3)*5"
   ,   Commas separate expressions    set /a "_num=2,_result=_num*5"
```

From [here](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

Comment: `set /a "yearminus1=%date:~6,10%-1"` gives me "Missing operand"

Comment: @johny why It seems you are catching a `/` in your substring operation -- try `set /a "y1=%date:~10,4% - 1"`

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I set a variable that is the year of last year?

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=/ tokens=3 " %%i in (`date /t`) do (
  echo Current year is %%i
  set /a "_lastyear=%%i-1"
  echo Last year is !_lastyear!
  )
endlocal
```

Output:

```
F:\test>test
Current year is 2016
Last year is 2015
```

In your particular case you should be able to use the following:

```
set_year=%date:~10,4%
set /a "_lastyear=%%i-1"
echo %_lastyear%
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [date](http://ss64.com/nt/date.html) - Display or change the date.Display or change the date.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

Comment: Actually I can. The problem in your case was that your date should be something like `2016/02/12` and by using 10 as an index parameter you couldn't extract the substring because it's too short (indexes ranging from 0 to 9). Try `echo %date%` or `echo %date:~0,4%` and it's going to work.

Comment: Regardless, my answer shows how to "subtract 1 from the sub string I've just captured?"

Comment: I added a few lines to the answer to address your specific case.